# Previous employment data in DS-160: unofficial employment

Tags: usa

I'm filling out the DS-160 Visa form online, and I'm curious about the "previous employers" part. I've been working in the same company for almost 3 years now, and this is the only employment I've ever had. This is also the company who's my sponsor for the H1-B visa.

The problem is, I never worked officially there, so I'm not sure how legally safe it is to list it as my employer, both in the form and in my resume. What should I do about it?

**EDIT:** By unofficial I mean working remotely from my country (Russia). I think I signed some document saying that I was an independent advisor or something, but by Russian law I was officially unemployed during this period.

Comment: Where were you working? In what sense was your employment unofficial?

Comment: Did you work in violation of immigration law (bad) or did you have some sort of independent contractor or subcontractor arrangement  (not so bad)?

Comment: The I-129 petition for an H-1B asks about previous employment. I think you want to match what was written there (which is why the lawyer who helped with the I-129 usually also helps with the DS-160).